# Building hierarchies from MySQL PHP when no Parent or Child IDs are pre-defined

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I am using MySQL 5.7 so understand Common Table Expressions are unavailable, but am trying to find a way to build a hierarchy based off a column based input.

For example, my table consists of the following...

| Region | Office | Person |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Region 1 | Office 1 | Employee 1 |
| Region 1 | Office 1 | Employee 2 |
| Region 1 | Office 2 | Employee 1 |
| Region 2 | Office 1 | Employee 1 |
| Region 2 | Office 2 | Employee 1 |
| Region 2 | Office 2 | Employee 2 |

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=049349ecdbf3369026e009dcb08b3c14

Originally I had asked (in a different question that was closed) for direction around how this could be achieved with dynamically generated IDs and ParentIDs, but it seems this isn't possible without extensive sub queries.  Thinking about this a different way, could this be achieved in PHP to build an array instead?

Assuming the result from the DB is as per the table...

```
<?php

$dbResponse = array(
  array(
    "Region" => "Region 1",
    "Office" => "Office 1",
    "Employee" => "Employee 1"
  ),
  array(
    "Region" => "Region 1",
    "Office" => "Office 1",
    "Employee" => "Employee 2"
  ),
  array(
    "Region" => "Region 1",
    "Office" => "Office 2",
    "Employee" => "Employee 1"
  ),
  array(
    "Region" => "Region 2",
    "Office" => "Office 1",
    "Employee" => "Employee 1"
  ) 
); // etc. etc. ...........


// Transformation here
```

How could it be transformed to produce this desired output?

```
$newOutput = array(
  array(
    "Item" => "Region 1",
    "Children" => array(
                    "Item" => "Office 1",
                    "Children" => array(
                                    "Item" => array("Employee 1", "Employee 2")
                                    )
                    ),
                    array(
                    "Item" => "Office 2",
                    "Children" => array(
                                    "Item" => array("Employee 1")
                                    )
                    ),
  ), 
  array(
    "Item" => "Region 2",
    "Children" => array(
                    "Item" => "Office 1",
                    "Children" => array(
                                    "Item" => array("Employee 1")
                                    )
                    )
  )  
);
```

Comment: Yes, this is simplified for the purposes of the question.  The actual dynamically generated table (from a view) contains roughly 300 rows and 6 levels - vs the 3 in the example.  The dependants are reading only.

Comment: If dependants are read only then improving the underlying data structure is trivial. If you add details of current view and underlying data structure I can suggest improvements. Or you could create a fiddle with tables, views and sample data and I will have a look. I had a look at the simplified structure presented in your question - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d3c62b211e04bdd5d2c8897f107464ec)

Comment: I've updated the fiddle to show ideally the desired output in SQL, having introduced a further level of Team as an example.  Unfortunately, the view is generated from many different underlying sources of data which I don't have control over - otherwise to your point it would make total sense to solve the underlying data issue first.  One thing I can safely say in this case is there will only ever be around 300 rows, so it's not a huge impact.  Also to  your point and your answer, a PHP array iteration may be the simplest solution in this scenario.

Comment: My mistake.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c9cbee78489760f94cb457a9bafed8f5

Comment: Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=375ce4804eb074328ae436031c3004a2) for building the hierarchy. I am not going to add all the detail to my answer as I don't think it represents the best solution to your problem. The php solution is fast enough for your small hierarchy. You could implement the hierarchy table and refresh it when required or based on a simple schedule but it won't add any value as you cannot clean up the underlying structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to translate the nesting into an array would be -

```php
$newOutput = [];

foreach ($dbResponse as $row) {
    $newOutput[$row['Region']][$row['Office']][] = $row['Employee'];
}
```

which would look like -

```
Array
(
    [Region 1] => Array
        (
            [Office 1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Employee 1
                    [1] => Employee 2
                )

            [Office 2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Employee 1
                )

        )

    [Region 2] => Array
        (
            [Office 1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Employee 1
                )

            [Office 2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Employee 1
                    [1] => Employee 2
                )

        )

)
```

But if you really need to achieve the structure suggested in your question, then you could do something like -

```php
$newOutput2 = [];

// initialise 2 counters
$r = $o = 0;

$previousRow = null;

foreach($dbResponse as $row) {
    if (is_null($previousRow)) {
        // no counter manipulation required
    } elseif ($previousRow['Region'] == $row['Region'] && $previousRow['Office'] != $row['Office']) {
        $o++;
    } elseif ($previousRow['Region'] != $row['Region']) {
        $r++;
        $o = 0;
    }

    $newOutput2[$r]['Item'] = $row['Region'];
    $newOutput2[$r]['Children'][$o]['Item'] = $row['Office'];
    $newOutput2[$r]['Children'][$o]['Children']['Item'][] = $row['Employee'];

    $previousRow = $row;
}
```

which would look like -

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Item] => Region 1
            [Children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Item] => Office 1
                            [Children] => Array
                                (
                                    [Item] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Employee 1
                                            [1] => Employee 2
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Item] => Office 2
                            [Children] => Array
                                (
                                    [Item] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Employee 1
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Item] => Region 2
            [Children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Item] => Office 1
                            [Children] => Array
                                (
                                    [Item] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Employee 1
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Item] => Office 2
                            [Children] => Array
                                (
                                    [Item] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Employee 1
                                            [1] => Employee 2
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

**UPDATE**
For your example with Teams added to the hierarchy you can add another level of depth to the loop -

```php
$newOutput3 = [];

// initialise 3 counters
$r = $o = $t = 0;

$previousRow = null;

foreach($dbResponse as $row) {
    if (is_null($previousRow)) {
        // no counter manipulation required
    } elseif ($previousRow['Region'] == $row['Region'] && $previousRow['Office'] == $row['Office'] && $previousRow['Team'] != $row['Team']) {
        $t++;
    } elseif ($previousRow['Region'] == $row['Region'] && $previousRow['Office'] != $row['Office']) {
        $o++;
        $t = 0;
    } elseif ($previousRow['Region'] != $row['Region']) {
        $r++;
        $o = $t = 0;
    }

    $newOutput3[$r]['Item'] = $row['Region'];
    $newOutput3[$r]['Children'][$o]['Item'] = $row['Office'];
    $newOutput3[$r]['Children'][$o]['Children'][$t]['Item'] = $row['Team'];
    $newOutput3[$r]['Children'][$o]['Children'][$t]['Children']['Item'][] = $row['Employee'];

    $previousRow = $row;
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you.  presumably if I wanted to add another level then I would have to extend the elseif statement, and create another counter?

Comment: Yes, you can add as many levels as you want. It is worth resolving the underlying issues as these problems will only get worse as your dataset grows and the application(s) get more complex.